# Nuxt vuex auth store is not updating my getters

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store

My getters are not updating reactive even though the store contains the data.

Here is my Code

```
function initialAuthState (): AuthState {
  return {
    token: undefined,
    currentUser: undefined,
    refreshToken: undefined
  }
}

export const store: AuthState = initialAuthState()

export const actions: ActionTree<AuthState, RootState> = {
  [AuthStoreActions.LOGIN]: async ({ commit }, payload: { employeeID: string, password?: string }): Promise<User> => {
    const response = await AuthRepository.login(payload)

    // Save Token and User
    commit(AuthStoreMutations.SET_TOKENS, { token: response.data.token, refreshToken: response.data.refreshToken })
    const user = User.parseFromObject(response.data.user)
    commit(AuthStoreMutations.SET_USER, user)
    return new User()
  },
  [AuthStoreActions.LOGOUT]: ({ commit }): void => {
    commit(AuthStoreMutations.CLEAR_STORE)
  }
}

export const mutations: MutationTree<AuthState> = {
  [AuthStoreMutations.SET_TOKENS]: (state: AuthState, value: { token: string, refreshToken: string }) => {
    state.token = value.token
    state.refreshToken = value.refreshToken
  },
  [AuthStoreMutations.SET_USER]: (state: AuthState, value: User) => {
    const t = {}
    Object.assign(t, value)
    state.currentUser = t as User
  },
  [AuthStoreMutations.CLEAR_STORE]: (state: AuthState) => {
    //state.token = null
    //state.refreshToken = null
    //state.currentUser = null
  }
}

export const getters: GetterTree<AuthState, RootState> = {
  [AuthStoreGetters.TOKEN]: (state: AuthState) => state.token,
  [AuthStoreGetters.REFRESH_TOKEN]: (state: AuthState) => state.refreshToken,
  [AuthStoreGetters.CURRENT_USER]: (state: AuthState) => {
    console.log(state.currentUser)
    if (state.currentUser) {
      // needs to be parsed because VuexPersistence does not keep type information
      return User.parseFromObject(state.currentUser)
    }
    return undefined
  }
}
```

And here is how i call my getter

```
  @AuthStore.Getter(AuthStoreGetters.TOKEN)
    private token?: string

  created () {
    console.log(this.token)
  }
```

The Data exists as you can see on this screenshot. The only way to update my getters is by reloading the website.

[image]

Comment: Is your `currentUser` state properly updated? If you don't get anything, it's probably because you do not get inside of the `if`.

Comment: Check in your devtools, I'd even say that you could manually trigger it via the Vue devtools or console to see if the getters are being updated.

Comment: I manually changed the values of all variables in devtools but it didnt update in getters.

Comment: I suppose `currentUser` is an object, hm strange that it doesn't update. I guess it will not work neither if you update the state via a button click. A [repro] would probably be needed here I guess.

Comment: Feel free to mark your answer as accepted when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the error.

```
export const store: AuthState = initialAuthState()
```

must be

```
export const state: AuthState = initialAuthState()
```

I hope this can help somebody else